# Having trouble creating an HTML drop down list from Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, dropdown

New to Google scripts. Trying to create a form with a dropdown list populated with one of the google sheets.

I found a couple of examples of this on the web and tried to create a dropdown list on a sidebar from Sheets. the spreadsheet has a tab named 'CARS'. Separately, I ran the Code.gs  which generates the values for the dropdown list and it is working.

However, the sidebar does not show the dropdown list. Here are the two files (HTML and gs) I am using. Thanks.

```
Code.gs

function getList() {
  console.log('cars')
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var carSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CARS");
  var LastRow = carSheet.getLastRow();
  console.log(LastRow)
  return carSheet.getRange(2,1,LastRow - 1, 2).getValues(); 
}

function startForm() {
  var form = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dropdownList');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
}

function addMenu() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom');
  menu.addItem('Dropdown List', 'startForm');
  menu.addToUi();
}
function onOpen(e)
{
  addMenu();
}

dropdownList.html



<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
  function loadCars() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar))
    console.log('in loadcars')
    {
      var carsSelect = document.getElementById("cars");
      console.log(ar)

      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = "";
      option.text = "";
      carsSelect.appendChild(option);

      ar.forEach(function(item,index)
      {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = item[1];
        option.text = item[0];
        carsSelect.appendChild(option);
      });

    }).getList();
  };
  function onSelect()
  {
    var carID = document.getElementById("cars").value;
    document.getElementById("carValue").innerHTML = carID;
  };
</script>
<html>
  <head>
    <h1>something</h1>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <select id="cars" onChange="onSelect()" ></select><br>
  <span id>"carValue"</span>
  <script>loadCars();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further review of the code in dropdowList.html found two errors. I had typed ="carValue" instead of <span id = "carValue>. The other error was
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar))
instead of
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar)
essentially causing the function not to run properly.
Sorry for the trouble